# Checking whether any two data frames in the global environment are identical

Tags: r

Is there a way to check whether any data frames in the global environment are identical to each other?

In other words, say I've just imported several (like a few dozen) files into R as data frames, and there's a possibility that some of them are duplicates of the same file that had been given different names. Is there a simple way to check if this is true, and if so which are the identical data frames? I know I can check whether a given pair of data frames is identical using

```
identical (df1, df2)
```

...but is there a way to find duplicates without doing this for every possible pair?

Comment: Sort of by definition, establishing this will require checking all possible pairs. The only question is whether you do it "manually" or write a function that does it for you.

Comment: You could speed it up by doing some pre-screening: for example, only compare objects with identical `dim` values

Comment: You could also prescreen on column names/types, row names, etc. The vetr package's `alike` function is good for this, I think http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/brodieG/vetr/blob/master/inst/doc/alike.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's possible to take this one level up and do all simultaneous comparisons, but you're able to compare multiple objects with a single object this way:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcarsHead <- head(mtcars)
Vectorize(identical, "x")(list(mtcars, mtcars1, mtcars2, mtcarsHead), mtcars)
```

TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

Comment: that is cool, thanks! But I still wonder if there is any way to do this that doesn't require a separate line of code for each data frame.

Comment: Although I'm sure there's a faster way to do this at scale, you could always do a for loop:

    for(i in 1:length(listofdataframes)) {
        print(Vectorize(identical, "x")(listofdataframes, listofdataframes[[i]]))
    }